# CMake - target_link_libraries and a real library name

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

I have an example library and two symbolic links:

```
libname.so -> libname.so.3
libname.so.3 -> libname.so.3.0
```

When I use this command:

```
target_link_libraries(app /home/theuser/libs/mylib/libname.so)
```

program works, but when I use following command: `target_link_libraries(app /home/theuser/libs/mylib/libname.so.3.0)`

I get an info: `error while loading shared libraries: libname.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` during program execution (after cmake and make steps). Why cmake can't get a lib directly (without symbolic links) ? Is it posiible ?

Answer (score 0):

We use this syntax daily without symlinks and it definitely works. Is it possible that it needs a "normal lib-like" file name into target_link_library? I would try to include .so files only in my link chain to see if it works first.